# Getting the error while updating GWT 2.5.1 to 2.11.0 and sencha GXT 3.1.1 to 4.1

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Quick question. Getting below error:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
     [java]          Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
     [java]             Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
     [java]                [ERROR] Line 107: Value 'ie8' in not a valid value for property 'user.agent'
```

using GWT 2.11.0, Sencha GXT 4.1 and Java17.
So, if any one can help me figuring out, how do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade GWT to 2.9.0. GXT 4.1 does not support newer versions of GWT. GWT 2.10.0 and newer dropped support for ie8-, ie9- and ie10-properties. Because of that, the properties are no longer available from GWT.

But keep in mind, there is a vulnerability in older GWT versions when using RPC. See: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9709

This issue is solved in GWT 2.10.1 & 2.11.0.

Another possible workaround might be to provide the properties.

Comment: When using GWT 2.9.0, I am facing issue of ant zipscanner, 
[ERROR] Line 19: Unexpected exception while processing element 'source'
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/types/ZipScanner
     [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.DefaultFilters.getScanner(DefaultFilters.java:240)
     [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.DefaultFilters$4.<init>(DefaultFilters.java:371)

Comment: Thanks, Now I moved forward from this issue, after downgrading GWT 2.9.0

Answer (score 0):

GXT 4.1 does support GWT to 2.9.0.
Refer to Docs - https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/Versions.html

Comment: When using GWT 2.9.0, I am facing issue of ant zipscanner, [ERROR] Line 19: Unexpected exception while processing element 'source' [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/types/ZipScanner [java] at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.DefaultFilters.getScanner(DefaultFilters.java:240) [java] at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.DefaultFilters$4.<init>(DefaultFilters.java:371)